# Cakephp 2.8 Why does my search_between function give me a warning?

Tags: cakephp, search, between

```
public function search_between() {

$min = $this->request->query['min'];
$max = $this->request->query['max']; 

$conditions = array('Ad.price BETWEEN ? AND ?' => array($min,$max));
$ads = $this->Anuncio->find('all',array('conditions' => $conditions));
$this->set('ads',$ads);

}
```

**Warning: strlen() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given.**

```
**Thank's for your help I'm new to asking questions here.**
```

Comment: Can you post where you are calling `strlen()`?

Comment: i don't call the strlen() its a warning that show cakephp when i pass the variables in a array($min,$max) to the Between :array('Ad.price BETWEEN ? AND ?' => array($min,$max) <- these array cause the warning but i don't know why. Thank's

Comment: Can you try dumping the sql generated by your request? That's a good way to start debugging this

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
public function search_between() {

$min = $this->request->query['min'];
$max = $this->request->query['max']; 

$conditions = array('Anuncio.price >=' => $min,'Anuncio.price <=' $max));
$ads = $this->Anuncio->find('all',array('conditions' => $conditions));
$this->set('ads',$ads);
```

Comment: I try these code before. Not work i correct some errors in your code and try but not work:  'Anuncio.price <='  <--- and these ----> 'Anuncio.price >=' ) show a error  Error: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax and not work. Thank's for the help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Cakephp mysql query it will works as like as cakephp query

```
if(!empty($min) && !empty($max)){
   $ads = $this->Anuncio->query('SELECT * from Anuncio WHERE Anuncio.price BETWEEN "'.$min.'" AND "'.$max.'"');
}

else{
$ads = $this->Anuncio->query('SELECT * from Anuncio');
}
```

Comment: I'm going to try your code And if it works I'll close the question. Thankk you so much!

Comment: I read on internet that strlen() not support a array and if you pass a array a warning is show.

Comment: I fix the problem changing the strlen to count in the file located on c:\wamp\your_project_name\\lib\Cake\Utility\CakeText.php line 221 and change $offset = $pos + strlen($val); to $offset = $pos + count($val); only change strlen to count and now the warning fly away a the code work as expected. Tnx for the help.